# How to use IList in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

How can we initialize an IList in Silverlight?

For exa following is not permitted as ArrayList is not supported in Silverlight:

```
IList list = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generic lists: `IList list = new List<SomeType>()`.